# iOS: Cost of asset format

Tags: ios, uikit, assets

In the previous places of employment I have used
to supply @3x png assets dodging @2x,
in the new place folks use pdfs to dodge *multiple assets per image* semisoft(?) requirement.

My understanding is that single @3x png is still cheaper than a pdf (exported from Figma in case it matters any)

What are the pros and cons of each method
of supplying assets?

```
1. lazy approach: @3x.png only
2. @2x & @3x (texture interpolation is better? faster?)
3. pdf
```

Bonus question: it would be interesting to know if SVG is mapped into CoreGraphics/CoreAnimation and what's that cost of THAT too.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "cost"? Actual designer time ($)? Memory? CPU?

Comment: Memory, CPU, GPU and other processing. Basically which is the least resource hungry approach. Designer does not care: she have done her design in Figma and that's it.

Comment: Well, you could use Instruments to test it, but probably just use PDF files. I doubt you will find a measurable difference

Comment: I expect at least SVG to be measurably different depending on the UIImageView size and svg complexity. As for PDF I expect it to be just an image with expensive metadata (compared to a lighter weight png). But I'm sure someone somewhere already did the digging that published the findings of some sorts.

Answer (score 1):

This is far too complex of an issue for Stack Overflow -- but to give you a couple things to think about...

If your SVG is complex - say it has 1,000 layers with various gradients and alpha values - and will only ever be displayed in your app at `300 x 200` points (that is, `600 x 400` and `900 x 600` pixels), you'd almost certainly want to render @2x and @3x pngs.

If your SVG is a simple-ish line drawing, and may be displayed at various scales and / or ratios, then SVG will give you better results.

If it takes your art department 10 hours to produce @2x and @3x png, but takes them 40 hours to produce an SVG, well?

If your image is a photograph?

If your image is a tab-bar icon?

And so on.

No idea what your app is about, but would 25% smaller storage matter? Would 50ms vs 75ms load time matter?

Best to do some research - there are many, many articles about this out there.